# Azure Deployment in VSTS with ARM Storage

Tags: azure, deployment, storage, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

Is there components that Will be able to deploy a project to Azure with ARM storage?
Currently, We are using "Azure Deployment" with Azure Classic, that is working properly.

But, in that components We can'T select the ARM subscription, just only the classic one.

Do you have any information about that?
Maybe the ARM template will be the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Cloud Services can only be associated with classic storage accounts.

More information, you can refer to: [How to create and deploy a cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-create-deploy-portal#before-you-begin).

So, you need to use Azure Deployment step/task with Azure Classic.